# PowerShell function with parameters?

Tags: powershell

I have a PoSH script that I can't figure out is not running..

```
function Connect-AD
{
    Param($mod,$cmd)
    Write-Host "$mod $cmd"
    Write-Host "`tConnecting to AD: $DC`n"
    $ADSession = New-PSsession -ComputerName $DC -Credential $MyCredential
    Invoke-Command -Command {Import-Module ('$mod') -Cmdlet ('$cmd')} -Session $ADSession
    Import-PSSession -Session $ADSession -Module ('$mod') -Prefix r | Out-Null
}
```

I then try to call this with..

```
Connect-AD -mod 'ActiveDirectory' -cmd 'Get-ADUser,New-ADUser'
```

But no mater what I do I keep getting..

> The specified module '$mod' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

The Write-Host inside the function outputs the parameters correctly, so it is getting that far. However it is not being passed into the Invoke-Command or Import-PSSession?

I've tried different ways to escape the parameters, etc.. but no luck.

What am I not doing correctly? Anyone able to help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Single quoted strings don't interpolate variables, `'$mod'` is a literal string  "dollar m o d".

And you probably need to read all the similar questions on passing parameters to Invoke-Command, because the command {} is running on another computer - how will it know what the variable `$mod` is on your computer?

[Passing string $variable to invoke-command scriptblock parameter -name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40247384/passing-string-variable-to-invoke-command-scriptblock-parameter-name)

[Powershell: How to pass parameter with invoke-command and -filepath remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465590/powershell-how-to-pass-parameter-with-invoke-command-and-filepath-remotely)

Something like

```
Invoke-Command -Command {param($mod, $cmd) Import-Module $mod -Cmdlet $cmd} -Session $ADSession -ArgumentList $mod,$cmd
```

---

**Help Links** (if available):

- [`Invoke-Command`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135225)
- [`Import-Module`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=141553)